# Sliding Window with gaps in-between in Pyspark Data Frame / Spark SQL

Tags: time-series, pyspark, windowing

I'm new to Pyspark, have used pandas for most of my data work. I'm trying to use *`Pyspark's`* Sliding window with `Window` function to make samples from my data set, ideally I want to slide my window with a gap between rows.

I'm wondering if there's a `step_size` parameter in either the `rangeBetween` or `rowsBetween` methods ( I couldn't find any in their documentation ).

`EXAMPLE: with set of rows as below (assume each row is a date)`

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

I want to be able to say, `choose the first 3 rows`, leave 2 rows in between, and then `choose the next 3 rows`

like: `A,B,C` ; `C,D,E` ; `E,F,G`; `G,H,I`  etc ...

I tried this:

```
windowSpec = Window.orderBy(func.col("column")).rangeBetween(start, end)
```

Obviously the above snipped only slides data logically between start and end, but doesn't give me the flexibility of skipping any rows in between if they logically satisfy the condition.

Any help is much appreciated. TIA !

Comment: You can always choose to filter out the data that is true per your logic. Something like retaining rows A, C, E, G.

Comment: @samkart Thanks for your generous response. We don't want to drop any rows yet, we want to experiment with different sliding techniques to see which data would work well with our underlying models.